# My new PS3 controller is not working

Tags: ps3, controllers

I bought a new controller for my PS3 because the original one broke down.
The new controller is a Marvo GT-018 and is compatible with PS3/PC/Android.
The things is it worked really well the first time I tried it but today when I hopped on to play some games it wouldn't connect.
I've tried to unplug the PS3, factory reset the PS3 and I even tried to plug it in my PC but nothing worked.
The PC would say there's a driver error but I couldn't fix that either.
There's no tutorial, forum regarding my problem with the PS3.

Note: I can't reset the controller because it doesn't have that small hole in the back and also the controller's "turbo" buttons (which lights up the interior of the controller) is working so I'm sure it's not the controller being broken.
I also tried a different PS3 (a slim one mine being fat) and it didn't work either, it showed the player 1 light but the buttons wouldn't work.

Comment: Is this a third-party product or official? Third-party controllers have been long known to be crappy (not saying all are, just a **lot** of them).

Comment: I don't really know tbh

Comment: Marvo is indeed a 3rd party manufacturer. You'd be better off contacting their support for troubleshooting, there's not much we can help you with here, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite sure that the controller is broken. I used a cheap controller from `Esperanza` brand and it works fine immediately after I plugged it into a USB port on PS3.

You should change this controller to the other one, or buy any from another brand, but don't be afraid of not expensive controllers.